# How to put two graphs on top each other with a specific layout

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

I hope I'm clear, it's my first question on the forum.

I have two graphs, "A" is just one variable and it is graphed above (I use the same code in both graphs but I filter by "Species" and "art") and "B" are several variables graphed with facet_wrap. The graph should look like this:

[image: This is how I want it to be]

but it looks like this:

[image: but it stays this way bad]

I have tried with grid.arrange and patchwork, but I can't accommodate the images well. Below I paste the code of the last output, with patchwork. Thank you very much for your time.

Here is the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(datos)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(esquisse)
library(patchwork)
library(gridExtra)

#1P.corruscans - todas las artes

frec_todas_artes <- Frecuencia_de_tallas_por_arte_2023 %>% 
  #filter(!(Arte %in% c("A – Todas juntas"))) %>%
  filter(Arte %in% "A – Todas juntas") %>%
  filter(Especie %in% "Pseudoplatystoma corruscans") %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = `Rango`, y = `Porcentaje`) +
  geom_col(fill = "#0c4c8a", color="white") + 
  labs(x="Largo total (mm)", y="Frecuencia relativa", title ="Pseudoplatystoma corruscans") +
  theme_bw () + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle = 90, vjust=0.5)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1600, by=100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(`Arte`), ncol=2)

frec_todas_artes

#2PCO - resto de las artes

frec_artes_facetas <- Frecuencia_de_tallas_por_arte_2023 %>% 
  filter(!(Arte %in% c("A – Todas juntas", "J – Maroma"))) %>%
  #filter(Arte %in% "A – Todas juntas") %>%
  filter(Especie %in% "Pseudoplatystoma corruscans") %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = `Rango`, y = `Porcentaje`) +
  geom_col(fill = "#0c4c8a", color="white") + 
  labs(x="Largo total (mm)", y="Frecuencia relativa") +
  theme_bw () + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle = 90, vjust=0.5)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1600, by=100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(`Arte`), ncol=2)

frec_artes_facetas



#grid.arrange(frec_todas_artes, frec_artes_facetas, nrow = 2, widths = c(5,10))

#intento de reordenar con patchwork

frec_todas_artes / frec_artes_facetas +

plot_layout(heights = c(1,2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use the `design` argument of `patchwork::plot_layout` which allows to specify the space you want to fill with a subplot, i.e. using

```
design <- 
"
#AA#
BBBB
"
```

you could add some space on the left and right of the plot in the first row.

Using some fake random example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

set.seed(123)

Frecuencia_de_tallas_por_arte_2023 <- data.frame(
  Rango = seq(600, 1600, 100),
  Porcentaje = runif(11 * 7, 0, 40),
  Arte = rep(LETTERS[1:7], each = 11)
)

frec_todas_artes <- Frecuencia_de_tallas_por_arte_2023 %>%
  filter(Arte %in% "A") %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = Rango, y = Porcentaje) +
  geom_col(fill = "#0c4c8a", color = "white") +
  labs(x = "Largo total (mm)", y = "Frecuencia relativa", title = "Pseudoplatystoma corruscans") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1600, by = 100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(`Arte`), ncol = 2)

frec_artes_facetas <- Frecuencia_de_tallas_por_arte_2023 %>%
  filter(!Arte %in% "A") %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = `Rango`, y = `Porcentaje`) +
  geom_col(fill = "#0c4c8a", color = "white") +
  labs(x = "Largo total (mm)", y = "Frecuencia relativa") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 8, angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1600, by = 100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(`Arte`), ncol = 2)

design <- 
"
#AA#
BBBB
"

frec_todas_artes / frec_artes_facetas +
  plot_layout(
    design = design, heights = c(1, 2)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Stefano! On the one hand I understood how to use the design argument of patchwork::plot_layout with the spacing to the left and right (whit #).
 On the other hand, I realized that I always looked at the result to the right of Rstudio, in the "plot" of the utilities, but never the "zoom". When I saw your example and that the output was correct, I tried to understand why it happened to me. Well, I didn't understand, but I learned that I should look by applying "zoom".
Now my graphs are showing fine.
If possible, I'll add an image showing this above.

Comment: Yep. It's not always about the Zoom. The general rule to keep in mind is that how your plot looks depends on the size of your plotting device, i.e. when you export your plot always set the width and height.

Comment: Could you give me one more help please? I can't configure the output correctly. I use ggsave("file_name.png", width = 470, height = 655, units = "px") and the final image is still very distorted. Only when I used "scale=1.5" the output file was visibly good.
Maybe I'm not understanding what is "..your plot looks depends on the size of your plotting device".

Comment: Hi Facundo. Everything fine. It's actually not that easy and I struggle with that, too. On the one hand we have the plot size and on the other hand the resolution. When displayed on the screen a res/dpi of 96 is used whereas `ggsave` uses a dpi of 300. As a consequence of this difference text looks much bigger. But as you already figured out you could use `scale` to correct for that. Based on my understanding I would use `scale=300/96`. For a discussion of the "text problem" see https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/.

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary for me to open the image with "zoom" to see that it was well designed and in proportions. on the left the image with "zoom", on the right the image as seen in "plot".

[image: Screenshot with two part of Rstudio]